# Query XML CLOB column to get sub XML in the column

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, clob

I have a CLOB column in my table which contains an XML. I want to fetch the xml after a specific tag to its ending tag i.e

Full XML in CLOB column

```
<ParentTag>
 <Location>ABC XYZ ....</Location>
 <Person>
  <Name>Mohsin</Name>
  <Age>23</Age>
 </Person>
</ParentTag>
```

What I am trying to fetch is something like this:

```
<Person>
  <Name>Mohsin</Name>
  <Age>23</Age>
</Person>
```

I have tried to use **dbms_lob.substr** and **dbms_lob.getlength** but that doesnt help as the sub XML may contain the `<Person>` tag starting at different bytes in different scenarios.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to parse the node out yourself with substrings. Oracle has extensive [XML support built-in](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm). You can do this with an [XMLQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions249.htm):

```
select xmlquery('/ParentTag/Person' passing xmltype(xml_clob) returning content)
  as xml_value
from your_table;

XML_VALUE                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Person><Name>Mohsin</Name><Age>23</Age></Person>
```

If your XML document (in the CLOB) can have multiple person nodes then you can use XMLTable instead to extract them all.

And if you want it to be a formatted string matching what you've shown, rather than an XML document, you can use an [XMLSerialize](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions252.htm#SQLRF06231) wrapper call:

```
select xmlserialize(content
  xmlquery('/ParentTag/Person' passing xmltype(xml_clob) returning content)
    as varchar2(100) indent size=2) as string_value
from your_table;

STRING_VALUE                                                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Person>                                                                        
  <Name>Mohsin</Name>                                                           
  <Age>23</Age>                                                                 
</Person>
```

Following up a comment, if you have anamespace you can [declare that as part of the XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb_xquery.htm#ADXDB5139):

```
select xmlquery('declare namespace NS4 = "http://soa.comptel.com/2011/02/instantlink"; /ParentTag/NS4:Person'
  passing xmltype(prov_request) returning content) as xml_value
from your_table;

select xmlserialize(content
  xmlquery('declare namespace NS4 = "http://soa.comptel.com/2011/02/instantlink"; /ParentTag/NS4:Person'
      passing xmltype(prov_request) returning content)
    as varchar2(150) indent size=2) as string_value
from your_table;
```

The extracted `Person` node will still have that namespace information though:

```
STRING_VALUE                                                                   
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<NS4:Person xmlns:NS4="http://soa.comptel.com/2011/02/instantlink">             
  <NS4:Name>Mohsin</NS4:Name>                                                   
  <NS4:Age>23</NS4:Age>                                                         
</NS4:Person>
```

Comment: Hi alex, Thank you very much for the answer. Pardon me to miss out on namespaces. I have namespace on the <Person> tag.

Comment: like this:
`code <ParentTag>
 <Location>ABC XYZ ....</Location>
 <NS4:Person xmlns:NS4="http://soa.comptel.com/2011/02/instantlink">
  <NS4:Name>Mohsin</NS4:Name>
  <NS4:Age>23</NS4:Age>
 </NS4:Person>
</ParentTag>`

I have tried using `code passing xmltype(prov_request) returning content) but i am unable to get the desired result.`

Comment: @user3081780 - updated with a version that handles the namespace.